Data pipeline with snowflake and dbt
I am trying to get hands on experience with snowflake and dbt building a data pipeline.
I'm working with a database from snowflake marketplae ('finance_economics') I have changed the name to finance and I have created data warehouse, db, role, and schema with dbt (dbt_db, dbt_wh, dbt_role, dbt_schema). I have defined my models staging and marts to handle them separately.
I have initialized dbt and dbt deps, everything is ok until dbt run.
I got this error :

"Database 'FINANCE' does not exist or not authorized."

I'm starting at this so I want to know how to manage the data ingestions with a db from snowflake marketplace.

What grants were provided to the role you created?
